# Variation of trace of symmetric powers

Tags: real-analysis, lie-groups

Consider the space $\mathrm{SU}(2)^\natural$ of conjugacy classes in $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. It has a natural identification with the interval $[0,\pi]$ with Haar measure $\frac{2}{\pi} \sin^2\theta\, \mathrm{d}\theta$, via the mapping 
$$
\theta \mapsto x_\theta = \begin{pmatrix} e^{i\theta} \\ & e^{-i\theta}\end{pmatrix} .
$$
Under this identification, the map $U_k\colon \mathrm{SU}(2)^\natural \to \mathbf{R}$ given by $U_k(x) = \mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{sym}^k x)$ is 
$$
U_k(\theta) = \frac{\sin((k+1)\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} .
$$

> I am wondering: is the exact value of the total variation of the functions $U_k$ known? In this context, this means: is there an exact formula (or asymptotic for)
>   $$
> \int_0^\pi |U_k'(\theta)|\, \mathrm{d}\theta ?
> $$

More generally, for $G$ a compact Lie group, we can identify $G^\natural$ with a quotient of Euclidean space via $\exp\colon \mathfrak{t} \to G^\natural$ for $\mathfrak{t}$ the Lie algebra of a maximal torus. Is there any reasonable formula for the total variation of the trace of an irreducible representation of $G$, in terms of the corresponding highest weight?

Comment: What do you mean by *variation*? For the usual compact Lie groups, the irreducible characters are similarly expressible (and the formula above is simply the character of the irreducible representations, restricted to a maximal torus).

Comment: I'm interested in the asymptomatics of the above integral as $k$ approaches infinity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the large-$k$ asymptotics I would first approximate $|U'_k(\theta)|$ by its envelope
$$F_k(\theta)=\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}\sin\theta},$$
plotted together for $k=50$:

[image]

The divergence of $F_k(\theta)$ at $\theta=0$ is cut-off at $\theta_1=1/k$, and similarly the divergence at $\theta=\pi$ is cut-off at $\theta_2=\pi-1/k$. Integration of $F_k(\theta)$ from $\theta_1$ to $\theta_2$ produces the asymptotics

$$\int_{0}^\pi |U'_k(\theta)|\,d\theta\rightarrow\sqrt{2}\,k\log(2k),\;\;k\gg 1.$$

A numerical evaluation of the integral (orange points) seems quite close to this asymptote (blue points):

[image]